# Nested Divs not stacking properly with content

Tags: html, css

I've an issue and need some help.

I've some nested divs that look fine - as long as there's no content. Once I added some test text, as the pages may have lots of content, spacing appeared above the divs. Here's a link to a screenshot of the issue:

http://www.stephencamper.com/screenshot/screenshot.gif

...and here's what the code looks like:

```css
html, body {
     margin: 0; 
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    #wrap {
     width: 1024px; 
     margin: auto;
    }
    
    #header {
     width: 982px; 
     height: 98px; 
     margin: auto;
    }
    
    #body_container {
     width: 982px;
    }
    
    #top_inner_bg {
     width: 982px; 
     background: #FFF url(images/top_inner_bg.gif) no-repeat top; height: 9px;
    }
    
    #sides_inner_bg {
     width: 982px; 
     background: #CCC url(images/vert_inner_bg.gif) repeat-x top; /* img ht is 2000px; it's supposed to fade transp after 770px; no sure if correct way to do this */
    }
    
    #bot_inner_bg {
     margin: auto; 
     width: 980px; 
     height: 100%; 
     background: #E8E7E3;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    
     <!-- header -->
        <div id="header">
         header here
        </div>
    
     <!-- body -->
        <div id="body_container">
            <div id="top_inner_bg"> </div>
      <div id="sides_inner_bg"> 
       <div id="bot_inner_bg">
                 <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <p>test</p>               
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

I looked for a solution and found something on margin overflow. I tried overflow: hidden;, but that didn't work. My divs don't float either, so the clearfix doesn't work for me. When I add a border to the divs, it works - but, well, now I have a border, and I don't want one, as I need the side images to seamlessly join up with the top_inner_bg div.

Help please!

Thanks.

-Stephen

Comment: Your screenshot returns a 403 error page.

Comment: I get a 404. Also you may wanna restrict what your browser spits out when you serve errors. It's tighter that way.

Comment: It  could be caused by css height on div <div id="top_inner_bg"> </div>

Answer (score 0):

The image you linked to wasn't working, so I assumed your issue was with the amount of white space between the header and the first p element. I fixed this by removing the header height, which was causing it to take up a lot of white space, and I decreasing the bottom-margin, which also was adding white space.

```css
 html, body {
         margin: 0; 
         padding: 0;
        }

        #wrap {
         width: 1024px; 
         margin: auto;
        }

        #header {
         width: 982px; 
         /* Removed height: 98px; */
         margin: auto;
         /* added margin-bottom*/
         margin-bottom: -2%;
        }

        #body_container {
         width: 982px;
        }

        #top_inner_bg {
         width: 982px; 
         background: #FFF url(images/top_inner_bg.gif) no-repeat top; height: 9px;
        }

        #sides_inner_bg {
         width: 982px; 
         background: #CCC url(images/vert_inner_bg.gif) repeat-x top; /* img ht is 2000px; it's supposed to fade transp after 770px; no sure if correct way to do this */
        }

        #bot_inner_bg {
         margin: auto; 
         width: 980px; 
         height: 100%; 
         background: #E8E7E3;
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

         <!-- header -->
            <div id="header">
             header here
            </div>

         <!-- body -->
            <div id="body_container">
                <div id="top_inner_bg"> </div>
          <div id="sides_inner_bg"> 
           <div id="bot_inner_bg">
                     <p>test</p>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <p>test</p>             
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```